# using nginx try_files config with react-router

Tags: nginx, react-router

I using react-router in my project,

as the document said,

I should add the `try_files` in nginx.conf

```
location / {
    root static/CKFM;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

the problem is, I have a search page,

and I want to let the search url has a keyword param, like

`/search/:keyword`

when I visit url like: `/search/some+words`

the path `/search/some+words` will also try index.html file, too.

[image]

thought the js program works fine,

but I still get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error

[image]

[image]

how to fix it?